# Fatal error: Class 'COM' not found jSMSPlugIn

Tags: php

I am using jSMSPlugIn.dll found in the net for modem free SMS
not sure what I am doing wrong here.

```
Fatal error: Class 'COM' not found .... on line 24
```

where in

```
$objComport4= new COM("jsmsplugin.smsversion1") or die ("Error on load");
```

here is my code and I am using Xampp

```
<?php
set_time_limit(1000) ;
 try{
    $objComport4= new COM("jsmsplugin.smsversion1") or die ("Error on load");
    $objComport4->SerialPort = "COM6";
    $objComport4->Baudrate = 9600;
    $objComport4->OpenSerialPort();
    $objComport4->ReadInbox();

    $Count = $objComport4->InboxReadCount();
    $count.=-1;

    print "
    <Table font='verdana'  cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' border='1'>
        <tr style='background-color:#678;font-size:12;color:#fff;padding:0 5 0 4px;'>    
            <th width=25>   </th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Number</th>
            <th>Content</th>
            <th>Date and Time</th>
        </tr>";
        $a = 0;
            for($i=0;$i<$Count;$i++) {
            if($a==1){
                $color = "fff3e3";
                $a = 0;

            }else{
                $color = "white";
                $a++;
            }
                $txtMessage =$objComport4->InboxReadTextMessage($i);
                $txtIndex =$objComport4->InboxReadSMSIndex($i);
                $txtStatus=$objComport4->InboxReadStatusType($i);
                $txtPhone=$objComport4->InboxReadPhone($i);
                $txtDate=$objComport4->InboxReadDateTime($i);
                print "<tr style='background-color:$color;font-size:11;padding:2 5 2 4px;'>
                <td>$txtIndex</td>
                <td width='70'>".strtolower($txtStatus)."</td>
                <td>".strtolower($txtPhone)."</td>
                <td width='250'>".strtolower($txtMessage)."</td>
                <td>".strtolower($txtDate)."</td>";


            }
            print "     </tr>
                    </Table>";

                if ($_REQUEST["SendSMS"] != ""){
                    if ($objSMS->SendMessage($_REQUEST["Message"],$_REQUEST["MobileNo"])) {
                        echo "Message Sent!";
                        $objComport4->CloseSerialport();
                    }else {
                        echo "Sending Failed!";
                        $objComport4->CloseSerialport();
                    }                   
                }


    $objComport4->CloseSerialport();
}
catch (com_exception $e) { 
    $objComport4->CloseSerialport();
     print $e . "\n"; 
} 

?>
```

Comment: Are you running Windows? Read the official [requirements](http://php.net/manual/en/com.requirements.php).

Comment: Have you enabled the extension in the `php.ini` file ([documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/com.installation.php))? If it still doesn't work afterward, verify whether you had chosen the correct `php.ini` file.